# windows ssh automatically login

Tags: windows, authentication, ssh, automation

I try to automatically login to the ssh from the batch file, and after authorization, execute my.sh script

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off

set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"


start "" /B cmd ssh user@192.168.1.183

timeout /t 1

%SendKeys% "{1}"

%SendKeys% "{ENTER}"

%SendKeys% "{bash my.sh}"

goto :EOF

@end

// JScript section
var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

The code is not working, but the essence of what should happen will help to understand

Tell me how to automate authorization through ssh and then after authorization execute my.sh script

Now I use this bat script

```
@echo off 
cd "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox"
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,225) DO (
echo %%i
VBoxManage startvm %%i
echo Wait while clone vm start and then press space in server type: bash my.sh %%i
pause
start putty.exe -ssh 192.168.1.%%i -l user -pw 1
echo After my.sh press space
pause
)
```

It connects via ssh to a remote machine and then waits until I press the space

Further, after it logged in to the remote machine

i type my command

bash my.sh {loop index}

And then I press the space

And so 225 times until the cycle ends

I would like to somehow automate the process of entering a command on a remote machine

For this, I tried to screw SendKeys here to enter this command, but I did not succeed.

Who knows how to do this?

Comment: What is your actual question? Do you need help making this code work? You should [edit] your question to describe exactly what happens when you run it, including any error messages that you get.

Comment: No error messages
this code just doesn't work like that
if I run it through the command line
ssh user@192.168.1.183
Next I enter the password 1
and after authorization through ssh I write
bash my.sh
Then it works, but I would like to automate it.